# Eclipse IDE for C/C++, gcc can't find *.c document

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I am working on a C project in Eclipse, the environment is windows X64,
When I tried to compile the program, it said:

> 11:54:29 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
>   TPCembarque **** Info: Internal Builder is used for build gcc
>   "-ID:\java workspace\TPCembarque\inc" "-ID:\java
>   workspace\TPCembarque\lib\" "-includeD:\java
>   workspace\TPCembarque\lib\libVirtualBoard.a" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
>   -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\main.o" "..\src\main.c"  gcc: error: workspace\TPCembarque\lib\libVirtualBoard.a -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
>   -fmessage-length=0 -o src\main.o ..\src\main.c : No such file or directory gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.
>
> 11:54:29 Build Finished (took 657ms)

so as a result it couldn't find main.c

All my data related to the project were saved in D:/systnum
and I created my project in D:/java workspace/TPCembarque.

I've already set the build environment as d:\systnum\MinGW\bin;d:\systnum\MSys\1.0\bin
I have already added the file main.c to the project [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSuAu.png)
Could anybody tell me how to let the Compiler find main.c? thanks!

Comment: Add the sources path to the project Path.

Comment: I think it is already added

Comment: Check it in **Project**-> **Properties** -> **C/C++ Build** -> **Environment** PATH variable

Comment: MINGW_HOME                                                               D:\systnum\MinGW                                                                              PATH ${MINGW_HOME}\bin;${MSYS_HOME}\bin;d:\systnum\MinGW\bin;d:\systnum\MSys\1.0\bin

Comment: These are the 2 variables, and paths are correct, but the value of MSYS_HOME is empty, but it is empty as default.

Comment: Are you sure that the probleem is main.c and not the libVirtualBoard.a library

Comment: Ihave already added libVirtualBoard.a to the folder lib

Comment: Could you post your make file?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, what is makefile? where can I find it in eclipse?

Comment: In your debug directory you may have: makefile and 3 .mk files.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to paste the makefile of your project?

I see a potential issue due to two different paths mentioned in your build log.

```
"src\main.o"  -> src is a folder in current directory
"..\src\main.c" -> src is a folder in the directory one folder back.
```